# How can we debug DLL (bulit with native C/C++) source with WPF/C# executable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli, visual-studio-debugging

Assume we have WPF/C# Project called **A** (`A.exe`).
It's using `DLL` built with C++/CLI ;which is project **B** (`B.Dll`)
And project **B** depends upon project **D**, which also a DLL built with native C/C++( `D.Dll`).

Simply `A.exe` -> uses `B.Dll` -> uses `D.Dll`

Here is my native environment is - Windows 10 ,Visual Studio 2017 ,Visual C/C++ 141 .NET 4.6.1/4.7.1.

Note that **C++/CLI** (CLR) project is a wrapper for native C/C++ functions, which means it's being used as a mediator between native **C/C++** and **WPF/C#** and also all projects built under one Visual Studio Solution, therefore respective project was added as reference to other project.

Startup program is `A.exe` as mentioned above which is WPF/C# project.

***Problem is I cannot debug C/C++ while running the project through Visual Studio 2017.***

Following things I have already tried:

- Set up working directory to built path(All DLLs,PDBs and exe there) in all projects.
- Set up Symbol path in Visual Studio 2017.
- Set  `Debugger Type` to `Mixed` within respective projects (under *Project properties -> Debugging*).
- Set(checked) `Use Managed Compatibility Mode`(*under Visual Studio Debug->Options->Debugging*).
- Set(checked) `Enable native code debugging` option in *WPF* project(*Project properties->Debug->Debugger engines*).

I couldn't break the execution at least on single breakpoint marked on C++ code.
Please help to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) ensure **D** and **B** are built in debug 2) that PDB is set to _Full_

Comment: @MickyD yeah all projects built in debug mode and generate full PDB.

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Modules.  Ensure the DLLs appear in the list, indicating that they are actually loaded.  Verify that Optimized = No, User Code = Yes, Symbol Status = Symbols loaded.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the direction found the issue.How stupid was I :*( .. , both `WPF exe` and `C.C++ DLL` name has same name on their module.. therefore symbols `pdb` for `CC++ DLL` module is not loaded .. I should have noticed ..that.. unfortunately I missed it.

Comment: Sorry guys!!! I found the issue.Traget out name for both Project `A` and Project `D` was identical.They have to be differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Target output file name** for each project should be differ,
else firstly loaded module's symbols will be visible to debugger.
In my case **A** and **D** had similar target out file names(not implies project names). Since **A** is the target executable,its `pdb` overwrites Projects **D**'s `pdb`.
Nevertheless,it's wise to configure things I mentioned in my questions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution here, please mark it as answer which could help more people.